# Google Spreadsheets: Handle new row automatically (Filter, Conditional Formatting, ...)

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I have a google spreadsheet and a nodejs app which is using the google api to update existing rows and add new rows. Now I have some things where I dont know what to do.

1) In column B there is a formula which uses values from other columns of that row. Is there an easy way to copy the formula with the index of the new row? Or must I iterate through the range before I send the request to get the index and then insert it to the formula? I think ArrayFormula in the first row will not work, because it is a complicated formula with some functions which are not working with ArrayFormula, like MAX.

2) I have a filter range over the whole table. But if I add a new row with my App, the range is not updated automatically. How can I do that?

3) Same with conditional formatting. If I add a new row, the range of the conditional formatting is not updated automatically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1- Use copyTo method instead of setValue(s) it will indexing automatically

2- you will find Filter options in Advanced Google Sheets you need to set it again because the #ref change this why the filter disappear same as conditional formatting